# Inserting URL in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Im currently working on iOS application which populate videos in UITableView by using MySQL as rdbms and xampp as a web server. I am facing difficulty in inserting URL in MySQL table. To make it more clear, i have 3 column which is NewID, NewsTitle and NewsVid in the table. when i insert the URL by query such as:

```
INSERT INTO `dbnews`.`Newsfeed` (`NewsID`, `NewsTitle`, `NewsVid`) VALUES ('1', 'Today's news', LOAD_FILE('Macintosh HD/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/video/Crime.mp4'))
```

An error prompt "#1048 - Column 'NewsVid' cannot be null"

Hoping on providing a guide for me to tackle this issues since i am in process of learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first - you have got unescaped char `'` in your SQL command - here: `'Today's news'`:

```
INSERT INTO `dbnews`.`Newsfeed` (`NewsID`, `NewsTitle`, `NewsVid`) VALUES ('1', 'Today's news', LOAD_FILE('Macintosh HD/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/video/Crime.mp4'))
                                                                                      ^ HERE
```

Edit your SQL to (you need to escape the `'` with backslash `\`):

```
INSERT INTO `dbnews`.`Newsfeed` (`NewsID`, `NewsTitle`, `NewsVid`) VALUES ('1', 'Today\'s news', LOAD_FILE('Macintosh HD/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/video/Crime.mp4'))
```

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENTS:**

And then you can try to store only link to file in database, no output of LOAD_FILE function. So your updated command will looks like:

```
INSERT INTO `dbnews`.`Newsfeed` (`NewsID`, `NewsTitle`, `NewsVid`) VALUES ('1', 'Today\'s news', 'Macintosh HD/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/video/Crime.mp4')
```

You can use LOAD_FILE when you will read data from database, something like:

```
// DB CONNECT
// DB READ DATA
LOAD_FILE($row['NewsVid']);
```

Comment: Thanks for response, i did edit my query as you have mention. I'm still getting a same error '#1048 - Column 'NewsVid' cannot be null'

Comment: Ok, now you need to check, if `LOAD_FILE('Macintosh HD/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/video/Crime.mp4')` returns some value. So what the function LOAD_FILE returning?

Comment: As I'm still new and learning, i understood that by LOAD_FILE i able to play my video file in browser by using php. Do point my mistake :)

Comment: Yes, but the MySQL error says: `Column 'NewsVid' cannot be null` and when you looks to your SQL command, you can see, that you adding output of `LOAD_FILE('Macintosh HD/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/video/Crime.mp4')` into `NewsVid` column. So maybe try to add `Macintosh HD/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/video/Crime.mp4` only and then use `LOAD_FILE` when you will read data from database.